# Datatables RowReordering not saving place/state

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, draggable, droppable

I am trying to save the order of my drag and drop rows in datatables but I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

I have `"bStateSave": true,` set in my initialization, but it doeen't seem to make a difference. I set up a fiddle, but I cannot get reordering to work with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1653/

Comment: It sounds like the function is being called before the script/dom loads

Comment: in the fiddle, can you fix it?

Comment: what do you mean with "saving place". your fiddle don't even work. The fiddle displays the error "TypeError: $(...).dataTable(...).rowReordering is not a function"